# bounce bug on resize element and animate scrolltop/scrollleft

Tags: jquery, resize, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I developed the plugin ascensor.js (http://kirkas.ch/ascensor/)
After rewriting it completely (whitout scrollto plugin) i experience some bug on the resize fonction.

When you do it, there is some bounce effect (chrome) and you can see small part of other floor, i know that every browser have different resize effect, but i'm wondering if there's a way to fix it.

Resize effect:
Chrome/Safari/Firefox: small bounce and see other floor
Opera: no resize effect until click up

Here the full plugin : http://kirkas.ch/ascensor/js/jquery.ascensor.js

And here the part about the resize fonction:

```
function resizeFloor(){
    var WW=$(window).width();
    var WH=$(window).height()

    if(params.Direction=='y'){$(node).stop().animate({scrollTop:(floor-1)*WH},1);}
    if(params.Direction=='x'){$(node).stop().animate({scrollLeft:(floor-1)*WW},1);}
    if(params.Direction=='chocolate'){
        var target = AscensorMap[StageOn-1].split('|');
        $(node).stop().animate({
        scrollLeft:(target[1]-1)*WW,
        scrollTop:(target[0]-1)*WH
        },1);
    }


    $(node).height(WH).width(WW).children(params.ChildType).each(function(){
        $(this).height(WH).width(WW);
    });

    if(params.Direction=='x'){
        $(node).children().css('position','absolute');
        $(node).children().each(function(index){$(this).css('left',index*WW);})
    }

    if(params.Direction=='chocolate'){
        $(node).children(params.ChildType).each(function(index){
            var CoordName = AscensorMap[index].split('|');
            $(this).css({'position':'absolute', 'left':(CoordName[1]-1)*WW, 'top':(CoordName[0]-1)*WH});
        });
    }
}
```

Also i'm quite new in JS development, so if you have any advice about syntax or critic about the system, i'm fully open.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finish to find by myself, instead of

```
$(node).stop().animate({
    scrollLeft:(target[1]-1)*WW,
    scrollTop:(target[0]-1)*WH
},1);
```

I should use

```
$(node).stop().scrollTop((target[0]-1)*WH).scrollLeft((target[1]-1)*WW);
```